# Apache + web.py application timing out

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a web.py application which I recently got to work with Apache using mod_wsgi. Everything worked till a few hours back.

Later when I decided to revisit the application it had stopped working. Apache was timing out without any errors logged in the error log or the access log. I didn't know how to debug this problem since I don't know what went wrong.

This is my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias /justcompare /var/www/justcompare/code.py

Alias /justcompare/static /var/www/justcompare/static

AddType text/html .py

<Directory /var/www/justcompare/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now however without my doing anything the application is working again. How do I identify the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Set:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

as explained in that.

Most likely you are using some third party extension module for Python that will not work properly in sub interpreters and it is deadlocking. Alternatively you have a multithreading issue in your own code if running in a multithread configuration.

If you are not on Windows, also make sure you read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html